# Interpreting Ventzell Boundary conditions

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am trying to understand the article "On boundary conditions for multidimensional Diffusion processes" of A. D. Ventzell (or Wentzell). I copy the images for greater convenience:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the footnote the author says:
[image]

I don't understand what are those transformations.

Is anyone familiar with this technique? Could you outline the main steps to obtain the boundary conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not as complicated as it seems, just write
$$F(x) = F(x) - F(x_0) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\partial F(x_0)}{\partial t_i(x)} t_i(x ) + F(x_0) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\partial F(x_0)}{\partial t_i(x)} t_i(x )  $$

the first two terms appear naturally, to the last term it suffices to write

$$\int  F(x) - F(x_0) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\partial F(x_0)}{\partial t_i(x)} t_i(x ){l(t)} d P(t,x_0,x)) =\\\int\frac{F(x) - F(x_0) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\partial F(x_0)}{\partial t_i(x)} t_i(x ){l(t)}}{ \sum_i t^2_i(x)  + n(x)}d\bigg( l(t) (\sum_i t^2_i(x)  + n(x)) P(t,x_0,dx)\bigg) $$